# How to prevent Mac OS keychain permission asked always

Tags: xcode, macos, swift4, keychain

My Mac Application stores sensible data in keychain. But when I am installing the new build for the application with same bundle identifier the keychain still asks for permission to access the keychain item which was previously entered by the mac application with same bundle identifier. So I want to know how to silent the keychain permission pop up for the same app ??

I dont want keychain to ask for permission for accessing items always for the same app. Also is there any way to mention the apps that can access the keychain item?

Comment: Is your app code-signed?

Comment: Access to keychain items generally depends on having matching code signatures between your versions, but it's more complicated than that; see the answer from Quinn “The Eskimo!” [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115425).

Comment: Thnaks @TheNextman, I got it right when i code signed, But the problem comes again when the app is renamed, once the app is renamed keychain again throws up the access permission.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson I wish if you could help me on the new problem also